# add a JComponent into a Chapter iText

Tags: java, itext, jcomponent

I'm using iText to create a pdf in Java, I need to print the Image of a JComponent into a Chapter before insert it into the document.
This is what I have so far:

```
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent( );

    PdfTemplate tp = cb.createTemplate( 300, 600 );
    Graphics2D g2d = tp.createGraphics( 300, 600, new DefaultFontMapper( )    );


    g2d.translate( pf.getImageableX( ), pf.getImageableY( ) );
    g2d.scale( 0.4d, 0.4d );
    jc.addNotify( );
    jc.validate( );
    jc.paint( g2d ); 
    cb.addTemplate( tp, 100, 200 );
    g2d.dispose( );
```

But I need to add it into the Chapter/Paragraph/Chunk instead of document directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the `PdfTemplate` inside an `Image` object:

```
Image img = Image.getInstance(tp);
```

Now you can use `img` in a `Chunk`, add it to a `Document`, and so on...

(Don't worry: this won't change your vector content into a raster image.)